# Creating set of JButtons according to retrieved database values

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm working on a POS system for a fast food restaurant. I've developed Adding, updating and deleting products using a MySQL Database. Now I need to create the POS GUI (using SWING) which the cashier uses to create the bill. The interface I have in  mind is like what MacDonald's uses, there's a set of buttons with the  product images. (I have stored BLOBS of products successfully)

example image  :

[image]

I have no idea on how to accomplish this, it would be awesome if its possible to generate a set of dynamic Jbuttons which gets the image of a product along with the name and price. Is this the best way to accomplish this? and how do I achieve this? A few details to put me on the correct path will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Top]

You have at least four containers, the top row, the bottom row and each row containing a separate container in the middle (for the buttons).

The basic layout for the rows might be a `GridLayout`, each row would probably use a `BorderLayout` with the nav buttons in the `WEST` and `EAST` positions.  `CENTER` container could use a `GridLayout`, but won't give you the look you're after.  You could use a `FlowLayout` and even a `GridBagLayout`, but you'd need to ensure the size of the buttons where correct for your needs

[image: Middle]

On the left I see a `JTable` and two `JPanel`s, containing the buttons, held together with a `GridBagLayout`.

On the right I see a `JList`.  See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.  You'll probably also want to have a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for details about how you could customise the look of the cells and [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for details about how to determine when the user changes the selection

Together, they are probably maintained by a `GridBagLayout` within a single container for ease of use

Along the button is probably another container using a `GridBagLayout`.

Altogether, they are probably held together by a `GridBagLayout`

Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) and [How to Use FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

You will need to look into the [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

In your case, it might be a little bit more complex since you have multiple grids, some of which seem to be nested within each other.

You should be able to allocate the grid dynamically and then leave it to the layout manager to distribute things evenly over the page.

Depending on the complexity of your layout, it might also be a good idea to look into the [`GridPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) provided by JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I look for you this problem and I find this solution ;

http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/06/create-dynamic-jbutton-with-image-and.html